# not_analyzed for a nested type on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a problem regarding performing facet search on a nested object.

Take for example i have the following document:

```
tags: [
   {
       tag: "tag0",
       tag_url: "http://xxxxxxx.com/tag/tag0/"
   },
   {
       tag: "tag1",
       tag_url: "http://xxxxxx.com/tag/tag1/"
   }
],

categories: [
    {
        category: "cat0",
        category_url: "http://xxxxxx.com/category/cat0/"
    },
    {
        category: "cat1",
        category_url: "http://xxxxxx.com/category/cat1/"
    }
],
```

and i want to perform a facet on `tags.tag` and `tags.tag_url`

And so i what mapping do i use in order to create `index:not_analyzed` for the nested fields ?

I have tried this mapping:

```
    mapping_data[mapping_name]["properties"] = {
        "tags.tag" : {
            "type": "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "tags.tag": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                    "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
        },
        "tags.tag_url" : {
            "type": "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "tags.tag_url": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                    "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
        },
        "categories.category" : {
            "type": "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "categories.category": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                    "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
        }, 
        "categories.category_url" : {
            "type": "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "categories.category_url": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                    "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
        },

}
```

and

```
mapping_data[mapping_name]["properties"] = {
        "tags" : {
            "type": "nested"
        },

        "categories" : {
            "type": "nested"
        }, 
}
```

But it does not give me the required result.

Using `type:nested`, still tokenizes the nested field, while `type: multi_field` cannot be expressed such that the nested field is `not_analyzed`. ( note that i used `tags.tag` in the `multi_field` variation, but to no avail. )

So, how to i express the mapping to achieve facet for nested documents ?

PS: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/ and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/ did not produce the outcome i need as i do not have the value_field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is the json mapping that you should be using for the `tags` nested field:

```
{
    "type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "tags" : {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "tag" : {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields" : {
                            "tag": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                            "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                        }
                    },
                    "tag_url" : {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields" : {
                            "tag_url": {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes"},
                            "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's perfectly fine to define a nested object that contains properties, which can be of whatever type, in your case `multi_field`.

You can then make the desired facet on the `tags.untouched` field like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : {} 
    },
    "facets": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "tags.tag.untouched",
          "size": 10
        },
        "nested" : "tags"
      }
    }
}
```

I tested this with the latest version of elasticsearch. Keep in mind that the way nested facets are made has changed since 0.90. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2606) to know more.